# Chrome extension: Syncing vuex - content.js and popup.js

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuex

How can I synchronize vuex state from content.js and popup.js?

I use 'vuex-persistedstate' and 'vuex-shared-mutations' and this works in popup.js, but in content.js I see an empty state and no mutations are transmitted from it.

Comment: You need to find a different library that uses extension [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to transfer the state, for example https://github.com/MitsuhaKitsune/vuex-webextensions or you can write one yourself.